# ng-repeat li's based on nested data, but without nesting the li's

Tags: angularjs

This is my data structure:

```
headings = [
  {name:'H1', items: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
  {name:'H2', items: ['d', 'e', 'f']}
];
```

I want to achive this:

```
<li ng-repeat="heading in headings" class="heading">{{ heading.name }}</li>
<li ng-repeat="item in heading">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

But in the second `ng-repeat`, `heading` does not exist. At the same time, I don't want to nest the second `li` inside of the first one.

Is this solvable?

I'm thinking some kind of comment solution, but I guess this is knockout syntax:

```
<!-- ng-repeat="heading in headings" -->
  <li class="heading">{{ heading.name }}</li>
  <li ng-repeat="item in heading">{{ item.name }}</li>
<!-- end-repeat -->
```

Comment: do you want to build table with headers?

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML markup that you would like to generate after the `ng-repeat` is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<li ng-repeat-start="heading in headings" class="heading">{{ heading.name }}</li>
<li ng-repeat="item in heading.items" ng-repeat-end>{{ item }}</li>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6X6aM/)

`ng-repeat-start` repeats everything up until and including the element with `ng-repeat-end`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the lis with an additional element and put ng-repeat on that element. If you have no other li items in the list, just put the ng-repeat on the list:

```
<ul ng-repeat="heading in headings">
  <li class="heading">{{ heading.name }}</li>
  <li ng-repeat="item in heading.items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6mLwq0IccQEzOhufAbI9?p=preview) for a runnable example.

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten them:

```
$scope.$watch('headings', function(headings) {
   $scope.flattened = [];
   angular.forEach(headings, function(heading) {
     angular.forEach(heading.items, function(item) {
        $scope.flattened.push({
            heading: heading,
            item: item
        });
     });
   });
});
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="flat in flattened">{{flat.item.name}}</li>
```